# Issue using FieldInfo = Array(Array(0, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(15, 2)) in my excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using FieldInfo in my excel macro in order to convert a fixed length text file to csv file. Whenever the last field is empty in the text file it simply gets ignored. I am looking to populate an empty field value instead in my output csv file. How do I achieve this ?
Script snippet:

```
txtFile = "Input.txt"
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    txtFile, Origin:=437 _
    , StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(15, 2)) _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Dim outputFile As String
    outputFile = "Output.csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=outputFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by populating a file header with required no of columns. This automatically forced the above code to insert empty columns in data rows.